# Trying to calculate power using while loop

Tags: c#

```
protected void calculatePowerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberInt = int.Parse(numberPowerTextBox.Text);
    int powerInt = int.Parse(powerTextBox.Text);
    int resultInt = 1; 

    while (numberInt > 0)
    {
        resultInt *= numberInt * powerInt;
        numberInt--;
        powerInt--;
    }
        resultTextBox.Text = resultInt.ToString();


}
```

Hi, im trying to calculate power when users enter a value into numberInt abd PowerInt using while loop

(numberInt to the power of powerInt).

the result will be display in resultTextBox....

but the result when i debug it alway equal to 0

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a loop for this?

Comment: It's not even power ... If powerInt>numberInt result always will be 0

Comment: What is wrong with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx Math.Pow function in C# ?

Comment: hi, for my workshop, i cannot use Math.Pow....

Comment: i dont know what im doing...:(

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
for (int i=0;i<powerInt;i++)
{
   resultInt*=numberInt;
}
```

or with while loop:

```
while(powerint-->0)
{
    resultInt*=numberInt;
}
```

Both answers are equivalent. They are calculating numberInt^powerInt.

If you don't know n-th power of number is multiplying number n-th times by the powered number. Like:

> 2^3 = 2*2*2
>
> 3^4 = 3*3*3*3

Answer (score 2):

Following code will do the job for you.

```
Math.Pow(numberInt , powerInt );
```

**Update,**
Since you can't use `Math.Pow` use the following,

```
int numberInt = int.Parse(numberPowerTextBox.Text);
int powerInt = int.Parse(powerTextBox.Text);
int resultInt = 1;
int i = 0;
while (powerInt > i) {
    resultInt = resultInt * numberInt;
    i++;
}
resultTextBox.Text = resultInt.ToString();
```

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal the `resultInt` should be initialized with `1`, otherwise the result is always `Zero`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try as well:

```
protected void calculatePowerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberInt = int.Parse(numberPowerTextBox.Text);
    int powerInt  = int.Parse(powerTextBox.Text);
    int resultInt = 1; 

    while (powerInt > 0)
    {
        resultInt *= numberInt;
        powerInt--;
    }
    resultTextBox.Text = resultInt.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the awesomely named Math.Pow method to do this calculation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not count power at all so it's wrong. Everytime powerInt < numberInt then it will result in 0!

Try this code below:

```
protected void calculatePowerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    int numberInt = int.Parse(numberPowerTextBox.Text);
    int powerInt = int.Parse(powerTextBox.Text);
    int resultInt = 1; 

    for(int i=0; i<powerInt; i++){
        resultInt *= numberInt;
    }
    resultTextBox.Text = resultInt.ToString();
}
```

The code above should be correct. :)